# How to remove the ^[[1m ^[[22m ^[[4m ^[[24m characters while keeping the newline?

Tags: special-characters

INPUT:

```
[user@notebook test]$ cat a.txt

music
musicsheet
sheetmusic

[user@notebook test]$ cat a.txt | cat -vte -
$
^[[1mmusic^[[22m$
^[[1mmusicsheet^[[22m$
^[[1msheetmusic^[[22m$
^[[4m^[[24m$
[user@notebook test]$
```

NEEDED OUTPUT (after removing these interesting characters):

```
[user@notebook test]$ cat a.txt 
music
musicsheet
sheetmusic
[user@notebook test]$ cat a.txt | cat -vte -
music$
musicsheet$
sheetmusic$
[user@notebook test]$
```

**Question**: How can I remove the interesting/unknown characters:

```
^[[1m
^[[22m
^[[4m
^[[24m
```

what are these characters? could there be more similar?

Trying to use tr to remove non-printable characters just makes these interesting chars visible and removes newline, what is both bad:

```
[user@notebook test]$ cat a.txt | tr -cd '[:print:]'
[1mmusic[22m[1mmusicsheet[22m[1msheetmusic[22m[4m[24m[user@notebook test]$
```

Comment: Those are color codes. How was this file generated? Did you maybe do something like `ls > a.txt`? It would be much simpler to just regenerate the file. And do you really need the `$`? Or do you just want a newline character at the end of each line? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Toby Speight's solution is fine. Some extra information:

Normally those are the ansi "special character" used to produce color, special effects, position the cursor, etc in the terminal.

for example `grep --color=always '[a-z]*music[a-z]*' files > output` will produce characters like that.

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g"
```

Sugestion: check if you have a `GREP_COLOR` deprecated variable set to `--color=always` or similar...

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove <kbd>CSI</kbd>...<kbd>m</kbd> sequences.  Knowing that they contain a sequence of numbers separated by `;`, you can use sed to replace each occurrence with an empty string:

```sh
esc=$'\e'
sed "s/$esc\[[0-9;]*m//g" a.txt
```

I'm using Bash syntax to write the escape character above.